# Merged, shared calendar in Exchange / Outlook

Tags: exchange, outlook, calendar

I've got a client suffering from XY problem. They keep trying to create a calendar for a fake user, and dumping information on that calendar to publish it to the rest of the company. What they really want is some sort of a report that all users can see, which will tell them who is free, who is busy, who is on vacation, etc...

There must be a way to do a calendar in outlook that functions like a search folder, where we can combine and display information from all users (or a subset of users) so that we can see Bob and Alice are on vacation today, and Eve has an appointment (marked private) from 1-3pm - without having to look at their calendars individually.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

in outlook if you open other users calendar you just tick a checkbox for all other open calendars so the calendars are shown overlaid
you can set all users calendars settings to show all info for other users except private events from the exchange powershell by running this script

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/19b98a56-42aa-4695-b07c-335d8322b64e